# Complex Access Query does not refresh in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

My Excel applications exports data (6 columns by 300+ rows) to Access DB once a minute.
After exporting, I try to import two sets of older values from Access to Excel.

The primary query is:

```sql
SELECT qryStDevPct.StDevPct, atblExcelIntraday.ValueClose  
FROM atblExcelIntraday 
LEFT JOIN qryStDevPct 
    ON atblExcelIntraday.SecurityID = qryStDevPct.SecurityID 
WHERE atblExcelIntraday.RecordDate Between #2022-05-04 13:55:59# And #2022-05-04 13:54:59# 
ORDER BY atblExcelIntraday.Ticker;
```

The internal Access qryStDevPct is:

```sql
SELECT atblExcelIntraday.SecurityID, 
       Avg(atblExcelIntraday.ValueClose) AS AvgP, 
       StDev(atblExcelIntraday.ValueClose) AS STD, 
       [STD]/[AvgP] AS StDevPct
FROM atblExcelIntraday 
INNER JOIN atblSecuritiesOpenPriceDaily 
   ON atblExcelIntraday.SecurityID = atblSecuritiesOpenPriceDaily.SecurityID
GROUP BY atblExcelIntraday.SecurityID;
```

The Price data from table always imports correctly, but `StDevPct` is either 0 or 1 30% of the time.

I can easily refresh it by doing manual "Data Refresh", but neither `.Calculate`, nor `.QueryTables("qryPriceDB_1").Refresh` work.

I could split it it two separate queries, but aside from programming it will take more time on the Excel end, and I'm trying to keep my main procedure to under 1,500 msec.

Please advise.

Comment: We need to see how queries are called in Excel VBA.

Comment: With  `[STD]/[AvgP] AS StDevPct` returning 0 or 1 (30% of the time?? what does it return other times?) the first thing I would suspect is integer division. Try converting one operand to double for testing ` CDbl([STD])/[AvgP] AS StDevPct', and run it directly in MsAccess. What do you get?